# When do javascript closures get cleared from memory

Tags: javascript, memory-management, closures

Let's say I have this application(in it's rudementary form)

```js
+function($) {
  var appName = "FooBarBaz";
  var appID = appName.replace(/[^a-z]+/gi, '').replace(/(.)([A-Z])/g, "$1-$2").toLowerCase()
  var Application = function($elem) {
     this.$el = $elem;
     this.appName = appName;
     this.appID = appID;
  }
  Application.prototype.getID = function() { 
    return this.appID;
  }
  Application.prototype.setID = function(newid) {
    this.appID = newid;
  }
  $.fn.appThing = function () { 
     var $this = $(this);
     var app = $this.data('app.'+appName);
     if(!app) { 
         $this.data(oc, (data = new Application(this)));
     }
  }
}(window.jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

now if a reload happens and the `$.fn.appThing` gets overwritten by a new(exact the same code, but freshly loaded) Application function and all the dom elements it was linked to are replaced to by new fresh html content, does the closure get removed from memory? Or will it retain itself somehow.

I'm curious to the general memory management logic behind the javascript standard, and when closure objects are released from memory, what the conditions are for release, so my memory won't fill up on a long haul of my program running.

Comment: Memory release for closures variable/object of the function will not happen until and unless there is a way to refer that function. 
In simple words: Closure variables/objects of the function gets cleared from memory when there is no way to refer that function.

I was not 100% confident about it that's why I put is as comment
Let other put some answers, Let me know if you find this informative

Comment: An enclosed variable is nothing else than a propert on an object, you don't hve access to (the object that holds the scope of the current function-call) aka. a regular reference to the JS-engine. ----- The JS engine decides when to run the GC. The GC cleans up all objects that are not referenced anymore by the global object (direct or indirect). Some references ain't that obvious, like the callback-functions you pass to `setTimeout` or an event-listener, and stuff like that; because, to be able to call you back, they have to keep (somewhere) a reference to the function they should call.

Comment: Yea, I know in theory it should get cleared when there are no references to DOM object, and the jquery FN function gets overwritten, then there are only circular references, but i'm not really sure if javascript implements it that way with closures, and I couldn't find a question explaining the memory management of closures, when it gets cleared, only explanations of how closures work.